# filter a list to a certain size in Kotlin/Java

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

I'm looking for an most efficient way in Kotlin/Java to filter a `List` down by a certain count and with the removal of filtered elements being applied across the collection in a uniformed fashion (i.e. - the elements to be removed span across the entire collection evenly);

For Example

- filter the following down to 5 [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] = [0,2,4,6,8]
- filter the following down to 2 [1,100,1000,10000] = [1,1000]

I came up with the following Kotlin extension function but it isn't working as expected (its return more than the requested count - e.g. initial size = 2593, newcount=125 - list=130)

```
fun <T> List<T>.filterDownByToCount(newCount: Int): List<T> {
    if (newCount < 0 || newCount >= this.size)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("prop ($newCount) must be between 1 and $newCount")
    val ratio = size / newCount
    val list = this.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % ratio == 0 }
    return list
}
```

ideally this function can handle anything from `0` up to `list.size-1` & I would like to use a library to do this (if possible) but can't seem to find any that fits my use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evenly filter a list down by a certain percentage - Kotlin/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417097/evenly-filter-a-list-down-by-a-certain-percentage-kotlin-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `size / newCount` is the *floor* of the ratio, so the ratio is too small, and hence you get more elements than you expect.

Use the ceiling instead:

```
val ratio = (size + newCount - 1) / newCount
```

For your example, this results in a list of size 124.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ratio is actually a fractional number, but you're doing integer arithmetic.

```
fun <T> List<T>.filterDownByToCount(newCount: Int): List<T> {
    if (newCount < 0 || newCount >= this.size)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("prop ($newCount) must be between 1 and $newCount")
    val ratio = size.toDouble() / newCount
    var accu = 0.0
    val list = this.filter { _ ->
        (accu <= 0).also { if (accu <= 0) accu += ratio; accu-- }
    }
    return list
}
```

You can change the ratio to be a `Double` - for your example, this returns a 125 element result.